# Angular Factory Object Persisting Over Storing in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, web

I've got a problem that i need help with in Angular 1.4.0.
I have a factory in angular which has a complex structure and method within so i am able to restore the factory back to its original state by calling the method.
The factory looks like this.

```
 angular.module('myApp').factory('itemFcty', function(){
 var currentValues = {};
 var default values {
       a = 1,
       b = 2,
       resetData : function(){
          currentValues = angular.extend(currentValues, defaultValues);
          return currentValues 
       };
   };
   defaultValues.resetData();
   return currentValues;
```

});
In order to add values to 'a' i call itemFcty.a = 2;
So this method works well when i want to overwrite all the values as and when required.
However i have been asked could i persist the data over a refresh. So i stringify the object into JSON. Like this:

localStorage.setItem('itemFcty', JSON.parse(itemFcty);

However i have hit a snag. The only data to be stored in the local storage is the

```
{a = 1,b = 2,}
```

I can add the method back in by doing this:-

```
itemFcty.resetData = function(){return currentValues = angular.extend(currentValues, defaultValues);}
```

This is the issue that now the factory does function the same way as before as i am not able to call the function as the call and return outside the default values object is not there any more i can cannot for the life of me work out how to add it back into as everything goes directly into the object as a whole.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

/*************************EDIT *****************************/
Ok, so i think that i havent explained the point very well.
My factory looks exactly like the above. The user hits refresh. The factory is stored in local storage. I get it back from local storage. But heres the issue.
It looks like this before local storage

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('itemFcty', function(){
 var currentValues = {};
 var defaultValues = {
       a : 1, 
       b : 2, 
       resetData : function(){
          angular.extend(currentValues, defaultValues); 
          // you don't have to return the values
       } // <------you can't use ; in the object properties
   };
   defaultValues.resetData();
   return currentValues;
});
```

Now when i get the data out f local storage and into the factory the factory then looks like this.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('itemFcty', function(){
     a : 1, 
     b : 2, 
});
```

I can add the reset data function back in, however as the factory does not contain current or default values, the reset data function will not work.
So basically i am asking how to make my factory, look the same as it does originally after i have reloaded data from the local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the variable back from localStorage? Also, there is a typo, I'd say `var default values`. In general stringifying does not account for methods, because that wouldn't make sense for other languages importing them.

Comment: Yes i load it back from local storage, the values are correct, however the function isn't in the JSON string, but thats fine because i can add it in afterwards. The problem is that the whole object loses the ability to call resetData().

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. `var default values {`, space separated variable and missing assignment operator `=`.
2. In the object you can assign values with `=` but `:`, so it will produce error `{ a = 1, b = 2 }`.

what you can do is:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('itemFcty', function(){
 var currentValues = {};
 var defaultValues = {  // <-------should have to be declared like this
       a : 1, // =  should be replaced with :
       b : 2, //  and here too.
       resetData : function(){
          angular.extend(currentValues, defaultValues); 
          // you don't have to return the values
       } // <------you can't use ; in the object properties
   };
   defaultValues.resetData();
   return currentValues;
});
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even see that equals in object declaration, I must be going blind.

Comment: I've added an edit, i dont think i explained my goal very well.